# How can you create a custom log in http request with Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to get my head around spring security for spring boot and all the information I can find online have to do with Spring boot MVC examples where the login.html page is created etc. What I need is a plain old HTTP GET /login page with a username and a password.

What I currently have for my WebSecurityConfig is this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).deleteCookies().and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }


    @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder (){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And my AuthenticationProviderConfig

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationProviderConfig {


    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Autowired
    AgentRepository agentRepository;


    @Bean(name="userDetailsService")
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        JdbcDaoImpl jdbcImpl = new JdbcDaoImpl();
        jdbcImpl.setDataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        jdbcImpl.setUsersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from agent where username=?");
        jdbcImpl.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("select b.username, a.role from agent_role a, agent b where b.username=? and a.agent_role_id=b.id");
        return jdbcImpl;
    }

}
```

This works fine but it's not ideal for my project.
Now every time a request comes in for any URL on my server the user will be asked for a username and a password through a server realm. In front end app terms that means that the developer needs to provide a basic authentication header with every request they send to the server.

Is there any way to customize the login so that it goes through a POST request like this one:

```
   @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void login(String username, String password){
        userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        //somehow login and create session?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following solution and it works.
Make a controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public SecurityUserResource login(@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("password") String password){
    SystemUserJpa userJpa = userService.login(name, password);
    return assembler.toResource(userJpa);
}
```

and in the SystemUserService looks like this :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SystemUserService {
@Autowired SystemUserRepository userRepo;
@Autowired SystemUserDetailsService userService;
@Autowired PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
@Autowired ResourceLoader loader;
@Autowired(required=false) SessionService sessionService;

/**
 * @param name
 * @param password
 * @return
 */
public SystemUserJpa login(String name,String password){
    // build authentication token for user
    SystemUserJpa userJpa = userRepo.findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(name);        
    if (userJpa==null) {
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException("login failed");
    }
    if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password,  userJpa.getEncryptedPassword())) {
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException("login failed");
    }
    UserDetails user = userService.loadUserByUsername(name);
    final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password,user.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    if (sessionService!=null) {
        sessionService.login(userJpa);
    }
    return userJpa;
}
```

}
The important is
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
After this, the user is  authenticated and this is sored in the session. When the next request from that user arrives, the same session is used, and because its authenticated he can acces pages thaat require authentication without getting asked for a passwordd again.